# SQL - COUNT() counts wrong number

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I am trying to count the number of profile visits, but it counts the wrong number. In the following example there should be 3 visits, but it counts 6! Anyone know what is wrong with it? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b43ea/8

```
SELECT *,
COUNT(profile_visitors.profile_id) AS visitorCount
FROM profile_visitors
LEFT JOIN user_login ON user_login.user_id = profile_visitors.user_id
WHERE profile_visitors.user_id = 1
```

Comment: You have two rows with user_id = 1 in the user_login table, so after the join you'll have 2*3 = 6 rows. Maybe the second row of the user_login table is meant to hold another user_id?

Comment: your sql fiddle has wrong data for table user_login.....its have duplicate userid 1 two times

Comment: Why do you need join the login table to get the count of profile visits? You can get the total count or per-user count perfectly from the profile_visitors only.  If you want to display user info with the count, you need group by first and join the users table (not the user_login table) later.

Comment: jpw is telling you your root problem.  Fix that first.

Comment: Your SQL is invalid, but MySQL chooses to return random ("indeterminate") results instead. You need a `group` when you aggregate and select additional columns. Every other DBMS will reject this SQL: http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/09/06/wrong-group-by-makes-your-queries-fragile/

Answer (score 1):

You need to Group By to count multiple rows,  So take the Star out of your query and add a group by user_id    also make it profile_visitors.*

Comment: While this is good advice (except for the last part) it won't solve the problem, which is caused by duplicate data.

Comment: @jpw:- I think OP has typo while putting data in table `user_login`, where OP wrongly put userid 1 two time

Answer (score 1):

The LEFT JOIN to user_login table provides no benefit to this question, but, the following query will get you the detail you want to see (assuming you only want to see the number of visits for user_id = 1):

```
SELECT COUNT(profile_visitors.profile_id) AS visitorCount
FROM profile_visitors
WHERE profile_visitors.user_id = 1
GROUP BY profile_visitors.profile_id
```

To see all visits by profile use:

```
SELECT profile_id, COUNT(profile_visitors.profile_id) AS visitorCount
FROM profile_visitors
GROUP BY profile_visitors.profile_id
```

Comment: Thank you, your snippit in combination with the snippit of jpw using DISTINCT solved the problem. Thanks eveybody for the help!

Answer (score 0):

you can use `WHERE IN ()` to compare if `profile_visitors.user_id` exist in `user_login`

```
SELECT  *,
COUNT(profile_visitors.user_id) AS visitorCount
FROM profile_visitors
WHERE profile_visitors.user_id IN (SELECT user_id FROM user_login )
```

result:

```
id  user_id   profile_id         visit_date             visitorCount
1   1              1          May, 10 2015 15:26:46           3
```

Comment: Oh, _try this_ is a great explanation :)

Comment: Lets hope the OP isn't using a MySQL version >= 5.7.5 which would make this query fail as it relies on non standard behaviour which has been disabled in later versions.

Comment: @DyrandzFamador It works in the current general available release though so no problem yet, but it might be in the future. The relevant part of the manual for reference is: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html